# Put list from variable into inline policy in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm creating **access_policies** as an inline policy in Terraform:
[image]

Is it possible to use one var with type of list instead of it? 
If yes, could you please give an example?

For me exception was:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_elasticsearch_domain.db: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_elasticsearch_domain.db: At column 1, line 1: output of an HIL expression must be a string, or a single list (argument 6 is TypeList) in:
```

Comment: You should include your policy as a code block, preferably including the full resource so people can actually run it, instead of a screenshot. You should also show it exactly as it causes the error with variables set/defaulted and if you have a different configuration that shows a different error or works but not how you want then show that too, explaining what is wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to describe policies next way:

iam.tf:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "example" {
    name   = "example_policy"
    path   = "/"
    policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
    statement {
      actions = ["*"]
      resources = ["*"]
      condition {
        test = "NotIpAddress"
        variable = "aws:SourceIp"
        values = "${var.ips}"
    }
  }
}
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "ips" {
    default = [
        "192.0.2.0/24",
        "203.0.113.0/24"
  ]
}
```